# How is a "factor model" different from a general linear model?

Tags: categorical-data, confirmatory-factor

Surprisingly, there isn't much about "factor model" on the web. Here is [one from Stanford](http://web.stanford.edu/~wfsharpe/mia/fac/mia_fac2.htm). As I read, I feel that the so-called "factor model" is just a general linear model, where$$Y=X\cdot\beta+\epsilon$$

Am I right on this? If this is correct, one follow-up question would be: can I conclude $$\text{Clock_Circle}=0.41\times \text{Clock_Method_Factor}+0.36\times \text{Executive_Functioning} +C+\epsilon$$ from this model graph?

[image]

Then, what can I conclude from the 0.44 curve between `Categories Animals` and `Categories Vegetables`?

Comment: Please explain your chart. What are the rectangles, the ellipses, the numbers. What is .44 arc?

Answer (score 1):

A "factor model" or a "multi-factor" model means just that the model involves multiple factors. It does not necessarily imply that the overall model is linear. Nested or piecewise linear factor models are not linear. You may also fit factors using trees or other techniques that produce non-linear models.